# Select text field after creating it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code which adds a new text fields to the page by clicking a button. The problem is that every time I add a new text field it is not automatically selected, so I can instantly do click+type (instead of click, then click on the text field, then type, then click again the button to add new text field).

This is the .js for adding elements:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 65;
var divcounter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
          newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

I've done some googling, but since English is not my native language it's really difficult to figure out what should I google for to solve this exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can focus an element by using `focus()`. Add at the end of the `else` in `addInput()`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('namefield');
inputs[inputs.length-1].focus();
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0bzLpy8j/)

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd like to suggest some changes to your initial JavaScript, though the demo below makes some guesses as to your HTML structure; hopefully the JavaScript will remain applicable.

So, assuming the following HTML is broadly similar (though why your variable is `newdiv` when it contains a `<tr>` element is a little confusing):

```
<div>
  <button id="demo">Add a new row</button>
  <table id="container">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nimi 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="namefield" class="field" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You could, as noted in [user3760780's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581262/82548), simply use the `focus()` method upon the last `<input>` element:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 65;
var divcounter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
          newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
    // querySelector('input') finds the first element matching
    // the CSS selector passed to the method (here: 'input')
    // contained within the node to which the method is chained
    // (here the 'newdiv' node); in this instance there is only
    // one <input> so it's the right one (and from a UI perspective
    // it's probably the first <input> in the <tr> you'd want to
    // focus):
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
     }
}
```

```js
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5; // lowered for demo purposes
var divcounter = 1;

function addInput(divName) {
  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  addInput(this.nextElementSibling.id);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="demo">Add a new row</button>
  <table id="container">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nimi 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="namefield" class="field" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

That said, while the above works, I'd recommend some changes:

```
function addInput(event) {
  // cancels the default action of the clicked element
  // to prevent form submission (if it's a <button> within a
  // <form>, or navigating to a new page (if it's an <a> element:
  event.preventDefault();

  // this approach finds the next element-sibling of the
  // clicked <button>, in this case the <table>:
  var self = this.nextElementSibling,
    // initialises the counter variable by finding
    // the number of <tr> elements held in the 'rows'
    // property of the <table>:
    counter = self.rows.length,
    // initialises the limit by looking at the custom
    // data-maxrows attribute of the <table> itself
    // (these approaches reduce the reliance on potentially
    // global variables) and uses parseInt() to convert
    // that string into a number:
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    // appending the newly-created <tr> to the <table>:
    self.appendChild(newdiv);

    // finding the <input> elment within the created <tr>
    // and focusing it:
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

// binds the addInput function (note the lack of parentheses) as
// the click event-handler for the element with the id of 'demo':
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```js
function addInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var self = this.nextElementSibling,
    counter = self.rows.length,
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    self.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="demo">Add a new row</button>
  <table id="container" data-maxrows="5">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nimi 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="namefield" class="field" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And to show an approach — similar to the above — that can find a `<table>` held within the same parent as the `<button>`:

```
function addInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // this is the only change, moving from the <button> to
  // its parentNode, to find the (first) element matching
  // the CSS selector:
  var self = this.parentNode.querySelector('table'),
    counter = self.rows.length,
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    self.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```js
function addInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var self = this.parentNode.querySelector('table'),
    counter = self.rows.length,
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    self.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

code {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="demo">Add a new row</button>
  <em>An arbitrary number of elements can exist here</em>
  <p>This is because here, the JavaScript looks to the <code>parentNode</code> of the <code>&lt;button&gt;</code> to find the <code>&lt;table&gt;</code> element</p>
  <table id="container" data-maxrows="5">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nimi 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="namefield" class="field" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And, finally, an approach that works — again — similarly to the above, and makes use of another custom `data-*` attribute (here `data-tableid`) on the `<button>` element:

```
  <button id="demo" data-tableid="container">Add a new row</button>
```

Giving the JavaScript:

```
function addInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // finding the element in the document whose id is equal
  // to the string held within the 'data-tableid' attribute:
  var self = document.getElementById(this.dataset.tableid),
    counter = self.rows.length,
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    self.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```js
function addInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var self = document.getElementById(this.dataset.tableid),
    counter = self.rows.length,
    limit = parseInt(self.dataset.maxrows, 10);

  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('tr');
    newdiv.className = "spaceUnder";
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<td>Nimi " + (counter + 1) + "</td> <td><input type='text' name='namefield' class='field'> </td>";

    self.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', addInput);
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="demo" data-tableid="container">Add a new row</button>
</div>
<div>
  <table id="container" data-maxrows="5">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nimi 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="namefield" class="field" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Selectors Module, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- HTML:

  - [Custom `data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).
  - [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows).
  - [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

You can give your inputs an id with your counter and then address them like this:

```
document.getElementById("input1").focus();
```